# Unpredictable behaviour when setting session with Ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables, session

I've run into a problem when setting a session variable with an ajax call. 
I have a button that adds an item to a shopping cart, which is handled by a file inside a subfolder.

I'm calling session_start() at the very beginning, like so:

```
<?php
//header.php
session_start();
echo session_id();
?>
```

I use this form to make initiate the ajax call in index.php:

```
<form class="add-cart-form" action="" method="POST"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $item[14]?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="qty" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="add_to_cart">
    <input type="submit" value="Add to shopping cart">
</form>
```

I have a separate script.js in the folder assets/scripts.js which executes the ajax call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".add-cart-form").on('submit', function(e) {
        $(".sb").addClass("blur");
        $("#overlay-wrap").slideToggle();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'handlers/cart-handler.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                $(".cart-size-number").html(data);
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

And finally the cart-handler.php which is supposed to update the session variable:

```
<?php
session_start();
#Add items to the shoppingcart array
if(isset($_POST["add_to_cart"])) {  
    if(isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"])) {  
        $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["shopping_cart"], 'item_id');  
        if(!in_array($_POST['id'], $item_array_id)) {  
            $item_array = array(
                  'item_qty'   => $_POST['qty'],  
                  'item_id'    => $_POST['id']
                );  
            array_push($_SESSION["shopping_cart"], $item_array); 
        }
    } else {  
        $item_array = array(  
                'item_qty'   => $_POST['qty'],  
                'item_id'    => $_POST['id'] 
            );  
        $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][0] = $item_array;
    }  
}
#Output amount of items  
echo sizeof($_SESSION['shopping_cart']);
?>
```

**The problem**
As you can see, in header.php i'm echoing out the session ID to check if it stays consistent. Whenever I make the ajax call by adding the product to the cart, either of the following happens randomly:

1. The session ID stays the same and everything works as expected
2. The session ID changes, not setting the session variable for the shopping cart

In case number two, the initial session that started in header.php is now overwitten by cart-handler.php. The shopping cart is still empty, but from this point forwards the shopping cart system works fine because it now keeps using the new session.

I would like to know why

```
session_start();
```

in cart-handler.php *sometimes* overrides the existing session and *sometimes* carries on with the original session? How can I change the flow of data so that the program always uses the original session?

**EDIT**
After testing it seems that the session_id changes when switching between pages. If I first load index.php, I get the session id. When I click on the next page, I see the same session id. But now when I go back to the index, the session ID changes. So it is being overwritten and after this, the session id stops changing between pages. How is this possible? I've almost lost 2 days trying to figure this out.

**EDIT 2**
Ok i've figured it out. I had some buttons redirecting to https://www.example.com but I was accessing the index at https://example.com which are apparently two seperate entities handeling their own unique sessions. I changed all links to full URLs and now force www via .htaccess so that the sessions stay consistent. So stupidly simple that this option didn't even cross my mind.

Comment: Hi. Is this a local environment? I assume the php files are on the same domain. If you check the request in the network debugger tab of the browser, do you see a Set-Cookie header there always (when it works and when it does not)?

Comment: _Small Note_ Place the `e.preventDefault();` at the beginning of the handler rather than the end

Comment: Is it just that the session is timing out?

Comment: preventDefault placement doesn't matter `Calling preventDefault() during any stage of event flow cancels the event` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: Hi, this is on a live server (everything worked fine locally). All files are on the same domain. I've checked the network tab and I see a difference in the Request Headers. If it fails to make the Ajax call it says 'Provisional headers are shown' and there are only a few items. When it does work, it shows all data such as post method, path to the file that needs to be executed etc. I don't see a set-cookie header though.